# why this code doesn't work?(axios and redux)

Tags: redux, next.js, axios

In my nextjs appI want to get user date by axios and set theme in initial state in redux.
I want when user enter any page or when refresh the page the get user data function execute.
To do this I put my function into user slice.
but it doesn't work and return a promise or 0.

```
import {createSlice} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from 'axios'
async function UserData(params) {
    await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/auth/getdata',{withCredentials:true})
    .then(res => {
    return res.data
    })
}
const user =  createSlice({
    name: 'user_data',
    initialState:UserData() ,
    reducers: {
//continue of code ....
```

Comment: try awaiting UserData()

Comment: I tried.it gives an error.

Comment: dont forget that you need to be in an `async` function to `await`